# free -m is showing total of 309 Mb for a system with 4GB RAM

Tags: linux, virtualization, memory, xen, top

**OS:Xen Cloud Platform 1.1 (XCP) modified centos, and xen server 5.0 running on intel i5**

**free -m**

```
               total       used        free     shared    buffers    cached
       Mem:     309         136        172        0         1          17
-/+ buffers/cache:         117         191
Swap:           511          7         504
```

**df -h**

```
none                  380M     0  380M   0% /dev/shm
```

**cat /proc/meminfo**

```
MemTotal:         316416 kB
MemFree:           79024 kB
Buffers:            5444 kB
Cached:            79304 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            48020 kB
Inactive:          64092 kB
Active(anon):      30572 kB
Inactive(anon):     1624 kB
Active(file):      17448 kB
Inactive(file):    62468 kB
Unevictable:        6436 kB
Mlocked:            6436 kB
HighTotal:             0 kB
HighFree:              0 kB
LowTotal:         316416 kB
LowFree:           79024 kB
SwapTotal:        524280 kB
SwapFree:         524280 kB
Dirty:               172 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         33876 kB
Mapped:            17864 kB
Shmem:               124 kB
Slab:              17100 kB
SReclaimable:       8276 kB
SUnreclaim:         8824 kB
KernelStack:        1464 kB
PageTables:            0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      682488 kB
Committed_AS:     647196 kB
VmallocTotal:     245752 kB
VmallocUsed:        4576 kB
VmallocChunk:     237148 kB
DirectMap4k:      754492 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB**
```

**top output**

```
Mem:    316416k total,   237992k used,    78424k free,     5636k buffers
Swap:   524280k total,        0k used,   524280k free,    79404k cached
```

**top sorted based on ram (shift+m)**

```
top - 14:59:20 up 29 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
0.0%st
Mem:    316416k total,   238008k used,    78408k free,     5708k
buffers
Swap:   524280k total,        0k used,   524280k free,    79440k
cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5942 root      17  -3  179m  12m 5492 S  0.3  4.2   0:05.72 xapi
 6964 root      20   0 11776 7672 2856 S  0.3  2.4   0:00.87 python
 5939 root      17  -3 21524 6092 2880 S  0.0  1.9   0:00.00 xapi
 6700 root      20   0 11768 5028 1644 S  0.0  1.6   0:00.16 python
 5740 ntp       20   0  4496 4496 3488 S  0.0  1.4   0:00.05 ntpd
 6398 root      20   0 27772 4052 1020 S  0.0  1.3   0:00.01 snapwatchd
 5634 root      20   0  170m 3620 2664 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.02 lwregd
 5527 root      RT   0  3432 3432 2708 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.04 multipathd
 7909 root      20   0 10168 2824 2268 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.03 sshd
 6128 root      20   0 29608 2792 1540 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.03 mpathalert
 7921 root      20   0  5152 2024 1268 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.05 bash
 5632 root      20   0  173m 1576 1036 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 lwsmd
 5241 root      10 -10  5988 1504  928 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.30 ovs-vswitchd
 5804 root      20   0  2992 1472  564 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.09 fe
 5909 root      20   0 11600 1452  912 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.04 squeezed
 5228 root      10 -10  5448 1440 1052 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.08 ovsdb-server
 5858 root      20   0  5360 1304  780 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.03 xenstored
 5831 root      20   0 12964 1212  756 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 v6d
 6552 root      20   0  5384 1108  572 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 crond
 8122 root      20   0  2404 1104  836 R  0.3  0.3   0:00.41 top
 6499 root      20   0  7180 1068  664 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 sshd
 5834 root      20   0 21112 1064  604 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.36 v6d
 6968 root      20   0  4492 1044  672 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 vncterm
 6969 root      20   0  2544 1044  912 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 dom0term.sh
 5240 root      10 -10  5880  832  272 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.28 ovs-vswitchd
 1527 root      16  -4  2364  744  396 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.24 udevd
    1 root      20   0  2156  664  564 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.21 init
 5563 rpc       20   0  1904  644  548 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 portmap
 6038 root      17  -3  5208  632  272 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 stunnel
 5376 root      20   0  1808  616  516 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 syslogd
 5227 root      10 -10  5444  556  280 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.27 ovsdb-server
 5861 root      20   0 10392  548  436 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 xenconsoled
 5869 root      20   0  3072  476  256 D  0.0  0.2   0:00.51 cdrommon
 6967 root      20   0  1752  472  404 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 agetty
 6965 root      20   0  1740  452  388 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 mingetty
```

**on BIOS 4 GB of installed RAM is showing.In the same machine earlier ubuntu 12.04 was running with out showing any RAM problem.**

**update:**

in the **xsconsole(xen console)>Hardware and BIOS Information>System memory>**

> total memory 4096 MB
>
> Populated memory sockets 2
>
> Total memory Sockets 4

Comment: Are you checking this on a VM or on the hypervisor? Are you sure your BIOS has detected 4GB of RAM?

Comment: What's the system? Latest BIOS? On the [Xen HCL](http://hcl.vmd.citrix.com/)?

Comment: @Chris S on top output and cat ouput its showing 4Gb but on free -m  its showing only 300 mb of total ram.

Comment: @chida checking on the hyperviosr.on top and /proc/meminfo output its showing 4 Gb RAM

Comment: @mgorven can u please tell how u formatted this.

Comment: @ananthan Have a look at the [revision history](http://serverfault.com/posts/416845/revisions) and the [markdown help](http://serverfault.com/editing-help).

Comment: @ananthan: Hmm? Your top output shows 300 MB RAM as well.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen ohh... that was a calculation misatake...why is it.. so in bios i can see two 2gb slots occupied

Comment: @ananthan That's not the questions I asked.

Comment: @ Chris S ,that is actually a feature of XCP,for allowing VM to take more RAM.Hyperviosr is limited to take 309 mb only(in this case).

Comment: many rdbms suck up all your ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dom0 memory is constrained by parameters in the extlinux boot param in/boot/extlinux.conf (look for the dom0_mem). Here in my conf below it is set to  752Mo, and it may vary after installation depending on the whole RAM of the server.

cat /boot/extlinux.conf

```
...
label xe
# XCP
kernel mboot.c32
append /boot/xen.gz dom0_mem=752M lowmem_emergency_pool=1M crashkernel=64M@32M console= vga=mode-0x0311 --- /boot/vmlinuz-2.6-xen root=LABEL=root-nddcwqei ro xencons=hvc console=hvc0 console=tty0 quiet vga=785 splash --- /boot/initrd-2.6-xen.img
...
```

RAM used by dom0 is not available for virtual machines, it is used for network bridging and physical block device handling, etc.

So it means that you have 4GiB - 300MiB of RAM available for your virtual machines.

Comment: thanks ZVIK...i was not aware of that...thanks alot...